# Dragged item does not stay on its new position

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am having this code which i am using to dynamically add new items

```
 <!Doctype html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
    .tr_deco{
    background-color:pink;
    border:1px solid red;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
    jQuery(".new_krud_slider").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('.krud_dom').append("<form name='krud_submit' action='admin.php?page=exchange_page' method='post'><table class='sortable'><tr class='tr_deco'><td>Slider Title</td><td><input type='text' /></td><td>Slider Description</td><td><textarea></textarea></td><td>Slider Location</td><td><input type='text' name='x' value='Jenna Doe'/></td><td><a href=''>I</a></td></tr><tr class='tr_deco'><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><button>Save</button></td><td><button>Delete</button></td></tr></table></form>");
jQuery( ".sortable" ).sortable();
    });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <a class="new_krud_slider" href="">make new</a>
    <table>
    <tr><td class="krud_dom"></td></tr>
</table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

​Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TRJXe/ 
I need the dragged item to stay where it has been dropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `sortable` jQuery widget. You need to use the `draggable` widget

```
jQuery( ".sortable" ).draggable();
```

This will let the item stay where it's dragged. Using `sortable` lets you drag items, yes, but when you let go, the item automatically sorts into its new location. Since you only have one item, it will always sort to the top; this is why it jumps back to the same spot after you let go of it.

**UPDATE**

After clarification on the nature of the question, the source of your problem is that you're calling `.sortable` on each individual form. To properly use the `sortable` jQuery UI widget, you need to call `.sortable()` on the element that **contains** all the elements you want to sort. In this case, that would be `.krud_dom`

So, you'll want to start by calling `.sortable` on `.krud_dom`, like so:

```
jQuery( ".krud_dom" ).sortable();
```

Then, each time you add a new form to the page, you need to "refresh" the widget, with another call to `.sortable`:

```
jQuery( ".krud_dom" ).sortable("refresh");
```

I've created a jsFiddle demo showing how this works:

[**--- jsFiddle DEMO ---**](http://jsfiddle.net/3fuKp/2/)

Comment: That works but the automatic intent of replacing an item is now gone.Once dragged and dropped,i have to arrange everything myself http://jsfiddle.net/dX58q/

Comment: Oh, I see now. You intend to use the `sortable` plugin, but the items are not sorting after dragging. Is that right?

Comment: In that case, the problem is that you're calling `.sortable` on each individual form. You need to call it on the containing element instead. I've updated my solution to address this.